# Sorting a table irrespective of which record a value belongs to

Tags: sql, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a table in which there are four columns named `Id`, `Product`, `ActualPrice`, `AskedPrice` with some data in it. I am trying to return and render the data from the table to an `html` page using `Knockout JS` in Asp.Net MVC. I am inserting the data into the table using following knockout js

```
self.add = function () {
        var payload = {
            Product:this.Product(), ActualPrice:this.ActualPrice(), AskedPrice:this.AskedPrice()
};
$.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

Now, I want to render the data from the table to HTML page sorted by `Product,ActualPrice, AskedPrice` in such a way that ActualPrice and AskedPrice need not be together.

For Example, I have the following SQL table

```
Id Product ActualPrice AskedPrice
1  Beer     10.00      9.00
2  Milk      5.99      5.95
3  Water     1.99      1.59
4  Milk      6.99      3.99
5  Water     2.55      1.55 
6  Milk      4.99      4.99
```

My html page should render as follows

```
Product ActualPrice AskedPrice
Beer     10.00        9.00
Milk     4.99         3.99
Milk     5.99         4.99
Milk     6.99         5.95
Water    1.99         1.55
Water    2.55         1.59
```

From the above we can see that for first record of `milk`, the `ActualPrice` and `AskedPrice` are not from the same record that is same `Id`, the `ActualPrice`  is from `Id=6` and `AskedPrice` is from `Id=4`.

HTML

```
 <!--ko foreach: products-->
<tr>

    <td data-bind="text: ActualPrice"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: AskedPrice"></td>
</tr>

<!--/ko-->
```

Is there a better way I could deal with this?

Comment: so within each product, list actual price low-to-high and asked price low-to-high, but without actually linking the price to the id of the product row, just the product name?

Comment: My table structure quite different to handle that way. I have added my html to the question. please check

Comment: That looks like it's going to be a whole world of pain for you that way. It sounds like you're saying you want a table where the product name is repeated N times, where N is the number of price pairs you have, then the price pairs displayed in two columns, where each column contains the price list from low to high for that product, with the actual price and asked price lists ordered entirely independent of the product Id which their database row has?

Comment: Yeah almost but it is just the askedprice that is independent of ProductId but actualprice is dependent on productId. Also both askedprice and actualprice are dependent on product name

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database you're using, but I'm most familiar with MySQL and will provide a solution that uses MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT Product,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ActualPrice ORDER BY ActualPrice) AS ActualPrices,
    GROUP_CONCAT(AskedPrice ORDER BY AskedPrice) AS AskedPrices
    FROM Products
    GROUP BY Product
    ORDER BY Product;
```

This will give you results like this:

```
Product  ActualPrice      AskedPrice
Beer     10.00            9.00
Milk     4.99,5.99,6.99   3.99,4.99,5.95
Water    1.99,2.55        1.55,1.59
```

So now the association and ordering is done, and you can do a little parsing to get the output formatted as you want.